# Как работает sp_whoisactive изнутри

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

В чём суть вопроса: разобраться откуда sp_whoisactive берёт данные, чтобы написать свой запрос для сервера.
Сам сижу над проектом для мониторинга sql серверов. Нашёл такую хранимую процедуру sp_whoisactive. Но проблема в том, что она устанавливается в master, что мне как раз и не радо. Решил заглянуть внутрь sp_whoisactive и нахлынуло уныние.
Возможно кто-то работал с sp_whoisactive и даже реализовывал сам часть её функционала. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как раз в нём.

Comment: `sp_helptext sp_whoisactive;`

Comment: maset = "master"? Так установите не в мастер, а куда там нужно

Comment: Может и можно было бы установить в конкретную БД, но это будет готовое решение. Поэтому и нужны свои запросы

Comment: Ну, смотрите DMV sys.dm_exec_...

Comment: Вот я и наткнулся в теле процедуры на sys. Правильно я предполагаю, что из них sp_whoisactive и берет данные?